# Team Foundation Version Control is not your current Source Control plug-in error

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs, visual-studio-2019

**Trying to download a project from Azure DevOps.**

I downloaded the code successfully, but when I try to bind this code to the source control (using Source Control Explorer), I received the next error "Team Foundation Version Control is not your current Source Control plug-in".

There is a link in this message error. When I clicked on it, I reach Options --> Source Control --> Plug-in Selection. In "Current Source Control plug-in" field is already selected "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server".

As I read in another place, I tried to select none in this option. Save. And select "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" again, but it is not working.

Sincerely, quite lost. Could you please give me any hint or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might have connected to a Git repository in your project. Use Team Explorer and Solution Explorer to manage your files in Git repos.

For more information, you could refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-source-control-explorer-manage-files-under-version-control?view=azure-devops#q-why-do-i-see-this-error-message-team-foundation-server-is-not-your-current-source-control-plug-in-click-here-to-set-the-current-source-control-plug-in).

Comment: Hello @Ging Yuan-MSFT. Thank for your response. Unfortunately, we are using TFS instead of GIT.